# Replicar página en theme de Wordpress a medida

Tags: css, wordpress

Saludos, tengo la siguiente página en un theme de Wordpress no hecho por mí, sino por un programador:

http://www.feriapixel.cl/feriamarketing/

La cual tiene su archivo template correspondiente llamado archive-feriamarketing.php

Me encargaron a mí crear una nueva página llamada feriaweb y que fuera idéntica a feriamarketing, para lo cual creé el archivo archive-feriaweb.php con el mismo contenido que feriamarketing, pero cambiando todo lo que decía feriamarketing por feriaweb.

Vi que cada uno de estos archivos de plantilla carga distintos estilos de los contenidos en style.css de acuerdo al id de la página.

Por ejemplo, con feriamarketing:

```css
#feria-marketing{}

#feria-marketing .seccion1{ background-color:#999; }
#feria-marketing .seccion1 .seccion-content{ }
#feria-marketing .seccion1 .wrap{ margin-top:100px; margin-bottom:100px; }

#feria-marketing .seccion2{ text-align:center; background-color:#333; color:#FFF; }
```

Y luego es llamado así al principio de archive-feriamarketing.php:

```
get_header(); ?><div class="pagina" id="feria-marketing">
```

Quise entonces copiar todo lo de  #feria-marketing{} en el archivo style.css y pegarlo justo debajo pero cambiando todo por #feria-web así:

```css
#feria-web{}

#feria-web .seccion1{ background-color:#999; }
#feria-web .seccion1 .seccion-content{ }
#feria-web .seccion1 .wrap{ margin-top:100px; margin-bottom:100px; }

#feria-web .seccion2{ text-align:center; background-color:#333; color:#FFF; }
```

y luego llamarlo así en archive-feriaweb.php:

```
get_header(); ?><div class="pagina" id="feria-marketing">
```

Pero esto no funcionó, así que por ahora lo tengo con el mismo id de feria-marketing. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿me faltó agregar algo?

Comment: El `id` es único. Eso sería realmente lo relevante al cambiar. Los estilos son reutilizables, así que no necesitabas cambiarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas los mismos estilos en esta nueva página, puedes dejar el mismo ID a nivel de markup, no hay problema con ello; si necesitas diferenciar algunos estilos, en ese caso si requieres la doble declaración, si aun quieres tener diferentes ID pero con los mismos estilos, puedes tener declaraciones del tipo:

```
#feria-web .seccion1,
#feria-marketing .seccion1  { background-color:#999; }
```

Lo que se me hace muy extraño es que digas que no ha funcionado (aun cuando no lo considero ideal, los estilos deberían haberse aplicado), probaste a borrar la caché del navegador?